# Fitting a site on different screen

Tags: html, css

I have a question what I couldn't find an answer for. 
Google Chrome has an option to change screen size so you could see if your site is responsive. By setting it to 1366x768 it seems to be perfect, but if using laptop/changing screen resolution to 1366x768 it doesn't fit suddenly only if changing zoom value to 80%. I know I'm not providing any code here, just wondering why such thing is happening?

Comment: Why all the -'s? Please comment next time your reason

Answer (score -1):

In my experience this has been due to using absolute pixel values and font sizes.  I personally have found using `em` and percentages `%` rather than `px` helps at times as well as using a responsive grid system, whether directly coded in CSS or through something like Bootstrap.  I would highly recommend Bootstrap as it is very easy to get into and will save you tons of time.